# Regex to read URL from ASPX File PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell Script which extracts URL's from ASPX files and test if their HTTP Statuscode is equal to 200.

I found the following Regex to get the URL:

```
$regex = "(http[s]?|[s]?ftp[s]?)(:\/\/)([^\s,]+)"
select-string -Path $path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

But the return looks like this:

```
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

as you can see, it doesn't really trim the end of the HTML Tags.

How can I edit my regex to get the URL without the HTML Tags in the end?

Comment: Replace `[^\s,]` with `[^\s,<>"]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the `[^\s,]` *negated character class*, you will see it matches *any char but whitespace and `,`*. If you look at the input you have, you will notice that `"` and `<` and `>` can all be matched with `[^\s,]`.

A fix for the current situation is to add `<>"` chars into the negated character class to make the regex engine "stop" when it comes across the `>`, `<` and `"` chars.

Note that since you extract whole matches, you may refactor the pattern a bit and remove unnecessary groupings and turn the first one into a non-capturing group:

```
$regex = '(?:http|s?ftp)s?://[^\s,<>"]+'
```

Mind that in .NET patterns, `/` does not need to be escaped (it is not a special regex metacharacter/operator).